# Silverlight Button not clickable when styling it

Tags: silverlight, styles

I'm trying to style a button with this :

```
    <Button Canvas.Top="200" Canvas.Left="170" Width="150" Height="150" 
            Click="Button_Click"
            Style="{StaticResource ButtonTestStyle}" />
```

and this :

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonTestStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <TextBlock Text="Test" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

but, when I click on the button, the click event isn't fired.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help,
Best regard

Comment: I'm not sure if you worked it out or not yet, but I've copied your code with one or two minor differences and it works just fine.  My button is in a StackPanel instead of on a Canvas, and also it has the name variable declared.  Other than that, exactly the same and working.

Comment: Unable to reproduce your code appears to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the transparent background.

Thanks for your help